# WSL(Ubuntu 18.04)でcurl -L (URL) | bashを実行するとエラーが出る

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, wsl, pyenv

こちら https://www.komee.org/entry/2018/10/25/120000 のブログを参考に、

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/raw/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash
```

を実行したら、次のように出力されました。

> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
>   curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443

"curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443"
と検索してみたのですが、よくわかりませんでした。
ご教授のほど、よろしくおねがいします。

---

解決しました。
こちらの[リンク](https://qiita.com/cactanaka/items/190665cfaf3b927766da)を参考に、
設定 -> ネットワーク -> 暗号化された接続のスキャン を「暗号化された接続をスキャンしない」にすることで、コマンドが通るようになりました。
コメントを下さった皆様ありがとうございました。

Comment: 私の手元の WSL (Windows 10 build 17134.523, Ubuntu 18.04) ではこの `curl` が成功しました。環境情報を更に追記して頂けると何かしら手掛かりになるかもしれません。

Comment: curl に `--verbose`  をつけると詳細出力されますので、それを質問に追記してもらえますか？

Comment: sayuriさんのリンクの通りにKasperskyの設定を変えたら、無事成功しました。一応環境を書いておきます。 OS : Windows 10 Home 1809, Kaspersky 19.0.0.1088

Answer (score 2, accepted):

当てずっぽうですが…

[Windows sybsystem for LinuxのSSL/TLSがKaspersky](https://qiita.com/cactanaka/items/190665cfaf3b927766da)に拒まれるといった話もあります。
ウィルス対策ソフトを無効化することで改善する可能性があります。

Comment: リンクの通り、暗号化された接続をスキャンしないにしたら、無事成功しました。ありがとうございます！