# pyoensslでOpenSSL.SSL.WantReadErrorが発生する

Tags: python, openssl

pyoensslでOpenSSL.SSL.WantReadErrorが発生します。
OpenSSLの不具合ではないかと考えており、アドバイスをお願いいたします。

■症状
https://github.com/opencv/open_model_zoo

をデバッグしています。

asn1crypto._ffi.LibraryNotFoundError: The library libcrypto could not be found

が発生するため、

（virtualenvパス）\Lib\site-packages\asn1crypto_perf_big_num_ctypes.py

cryptoをlibcryptoに変更しました。
該当箇所のエラーは解消しましたが、
その先で、

(virtualenvパス)\Lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py
1620行

```
error = _lib.SSL_get_error(ssl, result)
if error == _lib.SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
    raise WantReadError()
```

で

OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError

が発生します。

■環境
Windows 10
virtualenv
Python 3.7.1
pyopenssl 19.0.0
Visual C++ 2017
OpenSSL 1.0.2、1.1.0、1.1.1

■備考
以下のリンクを参考に解消を試みましたが、上記で行き詰まりました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302516/where-to-get-and-install-crypto-dll-on-64-bit-windows

Comment: ウィルス（対策）ソフトの影響はないでしょうか？ OpenSSLは[稀によく](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/52459/4236)引っかかりますが。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己レスです。
原因は特定できていませんが、
Visual Studioをデバッグ無しで実行すると、動作することが分かりました。